# Grails 3 scaffolding error when running Application class

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I created a trivial Grails 3.0.1 application and loaded it into IntelliJ IDEA by importing the `build.gradle` file. The recommended way to run the app through IDEA is to execute the `Application.groovy` class in the `init` folder.

Doing that started the app, and I was able to browse to the "Welcome to Grails" page, but when I tried to access any of the controllers I get:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 7 at column 12: Opening and ending tag mismatch: meta line 0 and head
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

default.list.label
```

in the browser. I have two domain classes and generated the controllers and views using `generate-all`.

I think something is failing in the <gsp> tags, but I don't know what.

If I start the application using `grails run-app`, the views work properly, so this is specifically an issue with `Application.groovy`.

Comment: tried this with idea 14.1.2 (create-app, create-domain-class, generate-all; run debug of Application.groovy, controller works).  any traces?  the problem seems to be around the non-closing <meta> usually used in html5 style code.

Comment: There were no errors in the console output, so no stack trace to report. I did a 'view source' and it looks like none of the gsp tags worked.

Comment: are you using the gradle wrapper from intellij?